# Remove Image From Header

Tags: gimp

I have a header, left side is a picture logo, and the right side is a few bars and address/phone number.  How can I remove the logo from the left side while keeping all the colors/info on the right side?

Comment: Can I see a sample of your image. and is it a layered project or a flat image?

Comment: @DCdaz it is a flat image.

Comment: With this information, we can only guess - and one guess would be: rectangle select around the logo, followed by the Del key. If you need something different, please improve your question.

Comment: Try moving your question to http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ - unless you want to do it programatically (i.e. write a scritp to that automatically on a number of images), _and_ attach a sample image - otherwise no one will be able to guess what you want. Even on graphicdesign, make ure you arenot asking a duplicate question.

Comment: @jsbueno will do thank you for the tip!

Comment: otherwise, just use the "crop" tool - or select the area witht eh lgoo and use bucket fill.